# New tab in system configuration auto selected and 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, tabs

I create a system tab but when I click Configuration then It selected my tab which order 200 (after catalog) and when i click My custom tab option it's give me a 404 page

My system.xml is

```
<config>
<tabs>
    <firstnewtab>
        <label>My custom tab</label>
        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
    </firstnewtab>
</tabs> 
<sections>
    <mytab_options>
        <label>My custom tab options</label>
        <tab>firstnewtab</tab>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <groups>
            <my_options1>
                <label>Options</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <sort_order>30</sort_order>    
                <fields>
                    <percent translate="label">
                        <label>Label 1</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </percent>
                </fields>
            </my_options1>
            <my_options2>
                <label>Options2</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <sort_order>40</sort_order>    
                <fields>
                    <percent2 translate="label">
                        <label>Label 2</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </percent2>
                </fields>
            </my_options2>
        </groups>
    </mytab_options>
</sections></config>
```

**UPDATE**
config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld>
</modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <helloworld>
            <class>Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld_Helper</class>
        </helloworld>
    </helpers>
</global></config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ACL permission is missing in your module. so add that to your module. ACL permissions are used to give proper permission for your modules configuration section.

File : `app\code\{codePool}\{Namespace}\{Module}\etc\adminhtml.xml`

```
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <mytab_options translate="title" module="cms">
                                        <title>Mytab Options</title>
                                    </mytab_options>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

After put this modifications, you need to clear the cache first.  Then you need to sign out from backend and login again to see your system config section.

Comment: Thanks Now 404 out. When I click that link that's work properly. But why it's selected first?  I set `<sort_order>200</sort_order>` but It selected when I click configuration.

Comment: @AbdusSalam I didnt get your question. put some higher number there. may be 1000. I think the answer resolved your problem which you have described in the question. So feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: About the preselection, please refer to http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73243/how-is-the-start-page-of-system-configuration-admin-system-config-index-define